# Regex help needed: Need to get number 82 from the following text

Tags: regex

I need to get the number 82 from the following text using a regex:

> uapJobStats,dataset=api,job=preprocessing,repo=edge,uapRegion=uap-trial-gs-us-central1 duration=82i,outputWriteDuration=8i,inputFileCount=9i

Does anyone know how to do it?

So far, I only came up with this:

```
(duration=\d+)
```

Comment: [`(?<=duration=)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/33TExi/1)

Answer (score 2):

Please check if the below regex works as expected. You've not mentioned any programming language. The below code is in Javascript and it uses capture group option `()` in regex to extract the matched number.

```js
var string="uapJobStats,dataset=api,job=preprocessing,repo=edge,uapRegion=uap-trial-gs-us-central1 duration=82i,outputWriteDuration=8i,inputFileCount=9i";
var regex = /duration=(\d+)i/;
var match = regex.exec(string);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - You've edited my answer to be case-insensitive? Actually I used i in the pattern because the user had i after the number.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It can do harm, because OP has `outputWriteDuration=8i` in his string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what's the point in using longer regex when we can use a shorter one and get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Po 'duration=\K\d+' file.txt
```

> `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match